# UINavigationController color and tint like the music.app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

How can I create a UINavigationController that looks exactly like the one in the current music app?

[image: Music.app Navigation Bar]

I tried ...

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.761 green:0.761 blue:0.761 alpha:1]];
```

but it's not quite what I was looking for. What's the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bar is using a gradient to create a z-axis rounding effect, so you'll need a pattern image which only needs to be a 4x44 px sliver of the gradient you want, then call `+[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];`